# Eclipse Vue.js Codemix Installation Error

Tags: eclipse, vue.js

I try to install Vue.js :: CodeMix from "eclipse Marketplace", but I end up with this error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Vue.js Pack :: CodeMix 1.1.0 (com.genuitec.eclipse.code.pack.vue.feature.group 1.1.0)
  Missing requirement: Code Local Web Server 3.6.0.202007202201 (com.genuitec.eclipse.code.localwebserver 3.6.0.202007202201) requires 'osgi.bundle; javax.servlet 3.1.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: CodeMix Essentials 3.6.0.202007221454 (com.genuitec.eclipse.code.feature.feature.group 3.6.0.202007221454)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.genuitec.eclipse.code.localwebserver [3.6.0.202007202201,3.6.0.202007202201]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Vue.js Pack :: CodeMix 1.1.0 (com.genuitec.eclipse.code.pack.vue.feature.group 1.1.0)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; pack.vue.feature.group 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Vue Extension Pack 3.6.0.202007221454 (pack.vue.feature.group 3.6.0.202007221454)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.genuitec.eclipse.code.feature.feature.group 0.0.0
```

I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling eclipse or even downloading the zip file to install manually but no luck.
Any suggestions?

Comment: It wants the `javax.servlet` plug-in but this was renamed to `jakarta.servlet-api` in Eclipse 4.20 (2021-06)

Comment: The Eclipse Marketplace just lists plugins and refers to update sites from which the plugin can be install, but the Eclipse Marketplace does not provide plugins. The CodeMix plugin is not from Eclipse and tries to cheat the Eclipse open source license by patching Eclipse at runtime (or to be more precise via loadtime weaving). This can cause issues and slow down Eclipse. There is Eclipse Wild Web Developer but it [does not yet support Vue.js for IP/license reasons](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/issues/83#issuecomment-778274839).

Answer (score 0):

Tasos, CodeMix isn't compatible with Eclipse 2021-12 or more recent versions, but you should be able to install it on 2021-09 with a patch. See this [forum post](https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/codemix-and-angular-ide-compatibility-issues-in-eclipse-2020-09/) for additional details. Feel free to contact us on the same forums, or email us at support@genuitec.com for further assistance.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I needed so I can start learning Vue.js.